Changing label colors in gge plot
I'm trying to change the color of the labels and it seems that the input of vector of colors works for lines and not for labels and the label color is just the first color of the vector list.
Maybe there is a workaround? Ideally I want to have colored labels according to a group lats say "drev", so several entries will be with the same color. Not sure if that is possible but its possible to do with a vector of colors at least.
Here is an example of what I'm trying to do with mpg data.
library(metan)
data <- mpg
gge_model <- gge(data,
                 env=cyl,
                 gen=manufacturer,
                 displ, #Choose trait
                 centering="environment",
                 scaling="none",
                 svp = "genotype",
                 by=NULL)


p <- plot(gge_model,
           type = 2,
           repel=TRUE,
           repulsion=1,
           max_overlaps = 20,
           col.gen = c(
             "black", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd",
             "#8c564b", "#e377c2", "#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22", "#17becf",
             "#393b79", "#637939", "#8c6d31", "#843c39", "#7b4173"
           ),
           col.env = "blue",
           line.type = 'solid', # in the manual solid should be default but it is dotted in fact
           title = FALSE,
           size.text.env = 3,
           size.text.gen = 3,
           size.line=2,
           plot_theme=theme_metan(grid = "none", col.grid = "white", color.background = "white"))+
  labs(title = element_text("p"))
p


Here is an approach that extracts plot elements from p and uses them to create a plot with ggplot2. Label placement for your original plot was not great, so I have employed ggrepel() to ensure labels do not overlap. As such, this solution is not as generalisable as I would like. If you need to create these regularly, I recommend using a legend instead.
First, load packages and create your plot:
library(metan)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

data <- mpg
gge_model <- gge(data,
                 env = cyl,
                 gen = manufacturer,
                 displ, #Choose trait
                 centering = "environment",
                 scaling = "none",
                 svp = "genotype",
                 by = NULL)

p <- plot(gge_model,
          type = 2,
          repel=TRUE,
          repulsion=1,
          max_overlaps = 20,
          col.gen = c(
            "black", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd",
            "#8c564b", "#e377c2", "#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22", "#17becf",
            "#393b79", "#637939", "#8c6d31", "#843c39", "#7b4173"
          ),
          col.env = "blue",
          line.type = 'solid', # in the manual solid should be default but it is dotted in fact
          title = FALSE,
          size.text.env = 3,
          size.text.gen = 3,
          size.line=2,
          plot_theme=theme_metan(grid = "none", col.grid = "white", color.background = "white")) +
  labs(title = element_text("p"))

If you run str(p), this will show the individual elements that constitute p. It is long, so I am not adding the entire result here, but here is an example of one element:
# Examine the plot text labels element 
head(p[[1]], 5)
#           d1           d2     type     label
# 1 -0.9523347 -0.005994725 genotype      audi
# 2  0.8794161 -0.492125224 genotype chevrolet
# 3  0.3250020  0.106245252 genotype     dodge
# 4  0.4362054  0.512391184 genotype      ford
# 5 -1.6713114 -0.042941542 genotype     honda

In order to make plotting easier, create a ggplot_build() version of p:
# Return ggplot build object 
p1 <- ggplot_build(p)

# Examine the equivalent ggplot text labels element
head(p1$data[[7]], 5)
#   colour size     label          x            y group PANEL angle hjust vjust alpha family fontface lineheight
# 1  black    3      audi -0.9523347 -0.005994725     1     1     0   0.5   0.5    NA               1        1.2
# 2  black    3 chevrolet  0.8794161 -0.492125224     1     1     0   0.5   0.5    NA               1        1.2
# 3  black    3     dodge  0.3250020  0.106245252     1     1     0   0.5   0.5    NA               1        1.2
# 4  black    3      ford  0.4362054  0.512391184     1     1     0   0.5   0.5    NA               1        1.2
# 5  black    3     honda -1.6713114 -0.042941542     1     1     0   0.5   0.5    NA               1        1.2

Run p1, and look for the elements you need. In this case:

p1$data[[1]] and p1$data[[2]] are the x and y axes lines
p1$data[[3]] is the 'barplot' data for each vehicle make
p1$data[[4]] and p1$data[[5]] are the x and y slope-intercept lines
p1$data[[7]] is the labels data

Combining the p1$data[[3]] and p1$data[[7]] elements will make plotting easier (in part because p1$data[[7]] does not have the desired colour values). Because they are different lengths, some extra manipulation is required:
# Return line geometry, add id for join
lines_df <- data.frame(p1$data[[3]]) |>
  mutate(id = 1:n())

# Return labels data, add id for join
labels_df <- data.frame(p1$data[[7]]) |>
  mutate(id = 1:n()) |>
  select(-colour)

# Set colour for Xn values (based on original plot, must be distinct from all other colour values)
x_col <- "blue"

# Join and identify whether object above/below x slope
df <- left_join(labels_df, 
                lines_df[, c("id", "xend", "yend", "colour")],
                by = "id") |>
  mutate_if(is.numeric, replace_na, 0) |>
    mutate(colour = if_else(is.na(colour), x_col, colour),
           lab_loc = if_else(y > yend, "up", "down"))

Using ggrepel takes a lot of trial and error. By adding the lab_loc column, this will reduce some complexity. For this reprex, it made sense to use the y values to determine "up" and "down". Adjust if necessary. The following draws on df, and some elements from p, such as the axis labels:
# Set plot variables for lines and labels (not exhaustive, add more for greater flexibility)
hline_w <- 0.1
abline_w <- 0.5
seg_w <- 2
txt_size <- 3.5
nudge_txt <- 0.6

ggplot() +
  geom_hline(data = p1$data[[1]],
             aes(yintercept = yintercept),
             linewidth = hline_w) +
  geom_vline(data = p1$data[[2]],
             aes(xintercept = xintercept),
             linewidth = hline_w) +
  geom_abline(data = p1$data[[4]],
              aes(intercept = intercept,
                  slope = slope, 
                  colour = colour),
              linewidth = abline_w) +
  geom_abline(data = p1$data[[5]],
              aes(intercept = intercept,
                  slope = slope, 
                  colour = colour),
              linewidth = abline_w) +
  geom_point(data = filter(df, colour == x_col),
             aes(x = x, y = y, colour = colour)) +
  geom_segment(data = filter(df, colour != x_col),
               aes(x = x, y = y, 
                   xend = xend, yend = yend, 
                   colour = colour),
               linewidth = seg_w) +
  geom_label_repel(data = filter(df, lab_loc == "down"),
                   aes(x = x, y = y, 
                       label = label,
                       colour = colour),
                   fill = "#ffffff80",
                   size = txt_size,
                   box.padding = 0.5, 
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   label.padding = 0,
                   label.size = NA,
                   nudge_y = nudge_txt  * -1, 
                   segment.size = 0.5, 
                   segment.color = "grey85", 
                   force = .1, 
                   max.overlaps = Inf) +
  geom_label_repel(data = filter(df, lab_loc == "up"),
                   aes(x = x, y = y, 
                       label = label,
                       colour = colour),
                   fill = "#ffffff80",
                   size = txt_size,
                   box.padding = 0.5, 
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   label.padding = 0,
                   label.size = NA,
                   nudge_y = nudge_txt, 
                   segment.size = 0.5, 
                   segment.color = "grey85", 
                   force = .1, 
                   max.overlaps = Inf) +
  scale_colour_identity() +
  labs(title = "p",
       x = p$labels$x,
       y = p$labels$y) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-2, 1.5),
                     breaks = seq(-2, 1.5, 0.5)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-2, 1.5),
                  ylim = c(-1.5, 1.5),
                  expand = FALSE) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())


